# Can we usefully turn an arbitrary syntactic consequence relation $\vdash$ into a preorder?

Tags: logic, order-theory

- Is it possible to turn the syntactic consequence relation $\vdash$ into a preorder?
- Does this perspective/construction have a name?
- Assuming it is possible, can we get this preorder by *considering all possible preorders and intersecting just the ones that respect the inference rules*?
- Is the induced preorder, assuming it's valid, useful for checking whether a given semantics "works"?
- I'm really *really* not sure what the proper way is to handle unconditional tautologies.

---

I was thinking earlier today whether it's possible to generate a preorder on well-formed formulas from inference rules today, and I concluded that it was. Here's my attempt to construct a preorder out of an arbitrary system specified by inference rules.

I will define $a^+$ as the set of all elements strictly above $a$ relative to some preorder $R$. I'm defining $a^+$ somewhat weirdly (without including $a$ itself) because I think it's related to the notion of a filter, but I'm really not sure at all and don't understand what filters are or why they exist.

$$ z \in a^+ \;\;\text{if and only if}\;\; R(a, z) \land a \ne z $$

First, let's impose the technical constraint that if a given system of inference rules has an inference rule with no premises, then it also has a designated truth constant $\top$ or a designated truth formula such as $1=1$. I don't think this is really necessary, I just want to always have a nonempty *island of truth* if that makes sense.

Suppose $\frac{\Gamma_1, \cdots, \Gamma_n}{\varphi}$ is an inference rule. If $\Gamma$ is empty, we replace it with a singleton set containing our truth constant.

If I have a given preorder $R$, I define consistency of $R$ with an inference rule as follows.

Let $S^+$, where $S$ is a set of well-formed formulas, be defined as follows using the definition of $a^+$ on well-formed formulas from earlier

$$ S^+ = \bigcup_{x \in S} x^+ $$

We can now talk about an inference rule being consistent with a possible relation $R$.

$$ \frac{\Gamma_1 \cdots \Gamma_n}{\varphi} \;\; \text{is consistent with $R$} \\ \textit{if and only if} \\ \Gamma ^ + = (\Gamma \cup \{\varphi\}) ^+ $$

The intuition is that an inference rule is valid if it only leads to conclusions that could have been reached already.

Additionally, I further impose the constraint that $R$ is closed under *uniform substitution of variables and syntactic metavariables* ... maybe that can be phrased as an inference rule, I'm not sure.

Anyway, I then consider the set of all possible preorders on $L$, let's call it $P$.

Let $P'$ denote the elements of $P$ that are consistent with every inference rule and closed under *uniform substitution of variables and syntactic metavariables*.

Then I take the intersection of all elements of $P'$, call it $\le'$.

$$ \le' \;\; \text{is equal to} \;\; \cap P' $$

So, I now have a preorder $\le'$ on the set of well-formed formulas in my logic.

I think this preorder is just $\vdash$ viewed through a different lens, so I'm wondering if we can rephrase questions about possible semantics in the following way.

Can I say that a given denotation function $\Delta$ *respects the semantics of logic* if and only if $\Delta(\varphi) \subset \Delta(\psi) \iff \varphi \le' \psi$?

My denotation function is a thing assigns interpretations to open well-formed formulas. It's probably inductively defined and may also assign interpretations to other things like function symbols and closed terms.

Here's an example for classical propositional calculus.

$$ V \in \Delta(\varphi) \\ \textit{if and only if} \\ \text{ $V$ is a set of variables and $V \subset \text{FV}(\varphi)$ and $\varphi$ holds if the true variables are exactly $V$ } $$

Comment: apologies if this is a stupid question, but isn't syntactic consequence a preorder anyway?  surely any sentence is a syntactic consequence of itself, and if $\phi\vdash\psi$ and $\psi\vdash\theta$, don't we have $\phi\vdash\theta$? indeed, can't we just concatenate a proof of $\psi$ from $\phi$ with a proof of $\theta$ from $\psi$ to get a proof of $\theta$ from $\phi$? this is slightly imprecise since $\vdash$ is technically a relation between _sets_ of formulas and formulas, not between formulas and formulas, but we can remedy this by just taking $\phi\vdash\psi$ to mean $\{\phi\}\vdash\psi$

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom, yes, it is a preorder anyway. My question as a whole may be a bit dumb. I'm trying to say it's the intersection of all the preorders that are compatible with the inference rules ... I want to use a collection of inference rules to generate a preorder ... similarly to how you can use a basis or subbasis to generate a topology. Also, I don't want to assume that my language has a conjunction connective. All the language about $\Gamma^+$ and $\varphi^+$ is meant to cover the fact that the inputs to an inference rule are sets of well-formed formulas.

Comment: oh, no worries, I don't think it's a dumb question at all! in general it's true that we can generate a preorder from _any_ binary relation $\mathcal{R}$ by taking the intersection of all preorders containing $\mathcal{R}$. this is the reflexive and transitive closure of $\mathcal{R}$, and it's what people mean by a "smallest" preorder containing $\mathcal{R}$. I'm not sure if there's more to say in the case of syntactic consequence, but I'll try to find some time later to read your question more thoroughly and respond to the points you make in that specific context

Comment: Perhaps look in [**Theory of Logical Calculi. Basic Theory of Consequence Operations**](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-015-6942-2) by Ryszard Wójcicki (1988). I don't have time now (and probably not the expertise anyway) to say more, and I also don't have a copy of this book with me now, although I've seen it often in university libraries over the past 30 years, and in fact I made use of it in a minor way recently (it's reference **[68]** in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/343402/15780)).